# I can't find PageChangeListener in ViewPager2.?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-viewpager, android-viewpager2

ViewPager2 PageChangeListener is not working like normal ViewPager.?

Comment: ViewPager2 provides `OnPageChangeCallback`.

Comment: Thats workingThanks

Answer (score 45, accepted):

There is `registerOnPageChangeCallback` method for that:

```
pager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(object: ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
            override fun onPageScrolled(
                position: Int,
                positionOffset: Float,
                positionOffsetPixels: Int
            ) {
                super.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset, positionOffsetPixels)
            }

            override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
                super.onPageSelected(position)
            }

            override fun onPageScrollStateChanged(state: Int) {
                super.onPageScrollStateChanged(state)
            }
        })
```

Comment: just 5 cents from my side:  don't forget to unregister the listener

Answer (score 7):

Below is the sample code for OnPageChangeListener in ViewPager2.

```
class ViewPager2PageChangeCallback(private val listener: (Int) -> Unit) : ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
    override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
            super.onPageSelected(position)
            when (position) {
               //YOUR CODE
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

In Java one can code it like this:

```
mViewPager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(new ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position,
            float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        super.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset, positionOffsetPixels);

        setProgress((position + positionOffset) / (mPageCount - 1));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this.

```
viewPager2.registerOnPageChangeCallback(new ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            super.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset, positionOffsetPixels);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            super.onPageSelected(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            super.onPageScrollStateChanged(state);
        }
    });
```